# SQL Count of results for each month in the Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query, easy to get a single month.

But I am trying to write a stored procedure to get all the months.

```
DECLARE @datemin date = '2019-10-01';
DECLARE @maxdate date = '2019-12-31' 

WHILE @datemin <= @maxdate 
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT
        A.sMonth, A.sYear, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        ClientsTable A
    CROSS APPLY 
        [dbo].[udfdob] (A.[DateOfBirth], @maxdate) B
    WHERE 
        sDate BETWEEN @datemin AND @maxdate
    GROUP BY   
        A.sMonth, A.sYear

    SET @datemin = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @datemin) 
END

--EXEC sp_clientWaiting
```

but the output appears multiple times:

[image]

How do I go about to get the result for every month in the year just once?

Currently I am having to type the dates manually for each month.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have a `while` loop if you only want one result set?

Comment: Does your data always contain at least one row per month?

Comment: thanks both, it works without the while loop. my apologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the WHILE

```
    DECLARE @datemin date = '2019-10-01';
    DECLARE @maxdate date = '2019-12-31' 


    SELECT
        A.sMonth, A.sYear, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        ClientsTable A
    CROSS APPLY 
        [dbo].[udfdob] (A.[DateOfBirth], @maxdate) B
    WHERE 
        sDate BETWEEN @datemin AND @maxdate
    GROUP BY   
        A.sMonth, A.sYear
```

From what you say it looks like the first time the loop runs, it's what you want. Every other iteration of the loop is just the first result set with yet another row removed

You don't need DISTINCT if you're GROUPing

Do you use the output of the udfdob function? It doesn't seem to appear in the query, so it's only effect would be if it were returning a resultset of multiple rows but it doesn't feel like it does...

Comment: I think you can probably also remove the CROSS APPLY, and the DISTINCT. If sMonth is part of the table, and simply replicates the month found in sDate, you could remove it from the table and use MONTH(sDate) or DATEPART(m,sDate)

Comment: sure I have done that and its perfect, what I wanted. appreciate it.

Comment: No probs. If there is ever no data for a particular month then it won't appear in the output. The simplest way to resolve that would be to generate some rows union'd onto the real data, with NULL in a column, and change the query from count(*) to count(column). We can advise if needs - just ask a new question and reference this comment/question